# How to refresh and obtain a non-expired auth token within a recursive ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, token

My concern comes with 2 main questions:

I'm following the tutorial to integrate the ["Google Sign-In into my web app"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin).

I have a working web application with a google id_token. After 1 hour, the error says the token is expiring, as shown below:

```
File "...\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "...\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "main.py", line 64, in passthru
    idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, g_requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)
  File "...\site-packages\google\oauth2\id_token.py", line 97, in verify_oauth2_token
    certs_url=_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CERTS_URL)
  File "...\site-packages\google\oauth2\id_token.py", line 78, in verify_token
    return jwt.decode(id_token, certs=certs, audience=audience)
  File "...\site-packages\google\auth\jwt.py", line 239, in decode
    _verify_iat_and_exp(payload)
  File "...\site-packages\google\auth\jwt.py", line 189, in _verify_iat_and_exp
    raise ValueError('Token expired, {} < {}'.format(latest, now))
ValueError: Token expired, 1517000578 < 1517006275
```

While I understand that there's 3 tokens (access_token, refresh_token, and id_token), I know the token is a JWT (as seen in the [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/auth/jwt.py) the error originates from) - but I think the expiring token is the id_token (not sure).

I created the token with Google's onSignIn(googleUser) function like so:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);              // Store id_token in local storage
}
```

Note: onSignIn() can only be executed by clicking on the Sign In Button that Google provides.

With that in mind, I want to refresh the token if it expires. I am hoping to do this with a recursive ajax function that looks something like this pseudo-code below:

```
function myRecursiveFunction() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/_db/bm/_api/simple/all",
        accepts: {json: "application/json"},
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", localStorage.getItem("id_token"));
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(query),

        success: function (data) {
            //Code to execute if successful ajax call

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            console.log(jqXHR)
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                console.log('Not connect.nVerify Network.');

            } else if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                console.log("Internal Server Error [401]");
                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);

            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                console.log("Requested page not found. [404]");
                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);

            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                console.log("Requested page not found. [500]");
                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);
            }
            // If there was a 401, 404, or 500 error, then I should have gotten a
            // id_token & now I want to re-run the ajax call to hopefully run 
            // 'success' code with a valid id_token.
            myRecursiveFunction()      
        }
    })
}

myRecursiveFunction()
```

So now, I have 2 issues:

1. The id_token cannot be refreshed without clicking on the 'Sign In' button. Is there a way to refresh the id_token without having to click the 'Sign In' button and invoke the onSignIn(googleUser) function? I would like to be able to simply invoke this code every time I need a new token.

   ```
       var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
       localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);
   ```
2. While I know Google offers a refresh token, I would prefer to more simply refresh my token in the event it expires. Is this method possible with the recursive 'pseudo-like code' above? Or is there a better method?

I see a lot of recursive ajax calls and refresh token info, but I haven't seen anyone trying the method above.

Thank you for any help!